# Exclude ".html" from URL's in Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Is it possible to some how get `www.mydomain.com/testing` to serve `www.mydomain.com/testing.html` using Google Cloud Storage?

With htaccess I use:

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You can specify which object represents the root of your website (for instance, serving index.html when the user goes to www.domain.com/), but that is a special case. Arbitrary URL rewrite rules are not supported.

The values you can configure are documented here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/website-configuration#step4

Answer (score 2):

[jterrace](https://stackoverflow.com/users/624900/jterrace) [wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41857496/7327479):

> You can serve HTML content without a .html suffix. It's important to
>   set the content-type though. For example, with gsutil:
>
> ```
> gsutil -h "Content-Type:text/html" cp /path/users/userProfile \
>     gs://www.website.com/userProfile
> ```

Comment: where did he write it?

Comment: There is a link on 'wrote' - http://stackoverflow.com/a/41857496/7327479

Comment: ah ok I thought all of the text _jterrace wrote_ was the same link.