# How to access html file on google storage bucket without pointing to file with html extension

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I'd like to let website users load userProfile.html when they request www.website.com/userProfile (without .html).
There is nothing about that in docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can serve HTML content without a .html suffix. It's important to set the content-type though. For example, with gsutil:

```
gsutil -h "Content-Type:text/html" cp /path/users/userProfile \
    gs://www.website.com/userProfile
```

Comment: I tried to achieve the result by uploading a .htaccess file to the bucket storage and it didn't work. Any idea why?